# how to select only objects that contain an array with more than N elements

Tags: jmespath

What's the right JMESPath expression to capture only the second object in the following array (because it has more than 2 objects in its `topics` array):

```
[{
  "topics": [
    "just one"
  ]
 },
 {
  "topics": [
    "first",
    "second",
    "third"
  ]
 }
]
```

I want it to spit out

```
{
  "topics": [
    "first",
    "second",
    "third"
  ]
}
```

I've tried `[? length(topics) > 2]` but `jp` complains about:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid token: tNumber
[? length(topics) > 2]
                    ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an input:

```
[{
  "topics": [
    "just one"
  ]
 },
 {
  "topics": [
    "first",
    "second",
    "third"
  ]
 }
]
```

use jmesExpression:

```
[?length(topics)>'2']
```

to get output:

```
[
  {
    "topics": [
      "first",
      "second",
      "third"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: so '2' has to be a string?